# ¿Qué hacen estos dos programas?

Tags: c, punteros

Ando aprendiendo punteros y en el libro que ando revisando me da este ejemplo. Sin embargo, cuando lo pongo en mi IDE (Visual Studio) sólo me manda una dirección de memoria.

Según yo, las funciones al ser llamadas cambiarían los valores a donde estan apuntando los punteros

---

```
  void datos(int *x, float *y, char *c) { 
    printf(“%d %f %c”,x, y, c); 
     *x=8; 
     *y=4.2; 
    *c='g'; } 
 void main(void)
{ 
int x=9; 
float y=44.6; 
char c='a'; 
datos (&x, &y, &c); 
printf(“%d %d %f %c”,x, y, c); // qué imprimirá?? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El programa tiene errores en **ambos** `printf( )`. En lugar de

```
printf(“%d %f %c”,x, y, c);
```

debería ser

```
printf(“%d %f %c”,*x, *y, *c);
```

y, en lugar de

```
printf(“%d %d %f %c”,x, y, c); // qué imprimirá??
```

debería de ser

```
printf(“ %d %f %c”,x, y, c); // qué imprimirá??
```

Con esos cambios, imprimirá exactamente lo que tu crees.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Juanjo!